# How to copy rows from one worksheet to another with styles using openxml?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I need to copy data from one worksheet to another worksheet which is in another `.xlsx` file. I try `clonenode` method with `deep copy mode` on each row and it copy rows fine but without cell formatting. How to copy rows from one worksheet to another with styles (cell formatting) using `openxml`?

Comment: is openxml a requirement or a preference?

Comment: Preference but I would like to find way to do that using openXml.

Comment: Could you copy the code you use ? And, at least, an example of cells you're trying to copy